Creating a table with multiple columns that show the count of another column in a separate table at the end of each month
In my created table that we can call table 1, I want to have a column that creates a new row at the end of each month and inside of that cell it will show the count for that month. In table two I will have a month column that says the month and year and the next column is this created dynamic column. It will get the count from a measure in table 2 and on the last day of that month add that count into table one in the next row.
I've tried multiple measures that will keep a live count on the month, but when the next month comes the previous months data is erased.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
